# Configure Specflow to test a dll with Microsoft DI

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, specflow

The scenario is as follows:

- I have created a .net dll that uses microsoft dependency injection.
- This dll can be used by either a web api or a windows service.
- I need to create a specflow test that calls a method and confirms its outcome.

This issue I have is in setting up Specflow as my experience of it is limited.

The dll has no host defined just a method to register its dependencies and its configuration.

All the examples I can see on the internet for specflow dont show how to setup a host to execute the dll and I'm confused.

Any examples say I should use new ServiceCollection() in a SceanrioDependencies method. However this has a compiler error of: Compiler Error CS0433 The type TypeName1 exists in both TypeName2 and TypeName3 And I cant make this go away.

Any help would be appreciated

I've tried installing the plugin SolidToken.SpecFlow.DependencyInjection and failed in making this work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you can't post your dll and original code for privacy reasons, try to set up a dummy project with a dummy DLL in the same way your real project is and post it in a repo like GitHub so the community can take a look to it.

Comment: SpecFlow supports a number of DI containers ([Autofac](https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Integrations/Autofac.html) and [Castle Windsor](https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Integrations/Windsor.html)). They require additional NuGet packages. I don't know if there is something for Microsoft DI.

Comment: The [Autofac SpecFlow plugin](https://github.com/SpecFlowOSS/SpecFlow/tree/master/Plugins/SpecFlow.Autofac.SpecFlowPlugin) on GitHub is an example of how you might write your own plugin to use Microsoft DI in SpecFlow. It looks like the answer is "write your own plugin."

Comment: @GregBurghardt OP: "I've tried installing the plugin SolidToken.SpecFlow.DependencyInjection and failed in making this work". [SolidToken's Specflow.DependencyInjection](https://github.com/solidtoken/SpecFlow.DependencyInjection)'s repo README: "SpecFlow plugin that **enables to use Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection** for resolving test dependencies". Rather than reinventing the wheel, probably it's worth a shot for OP to delve into why they are unable to make this existing plugin work, since it looks like it's exactly the right tool for OP's scenario.

Comment: I have tried repeatedly to make this work and it doesnt happen however I no longer need to complete the solution so thanks anyway.